My SSD is disconecting and reconecting imediatly on USB-C
I'm using Linux Mint on a HP Pavilion 17-cd1119nf.
Recently, i bought a SSD T7 of samsung.
When i plug it on USB-C, it get disconect then imediatly reconect when i'm using it. It can be when i transfert file on it or when i look photo from it.
The problem don't happen when the SSD is plug on USB-A port.
Here what I have with -Tsudo dmesg -T
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 2
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 210798873 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 17 prio class 0
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 210800921 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 17 prio class 0
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 210802969 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 26 prio class 0
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1950624425 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 6 prio class 0
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] Aborting journal on device sda1-8.
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 210805017 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 17 prio class 0
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_journal_check_start:83: comm kworker/u16:0: Detected aborted journal
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 210807065 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_end_bio:344: I/O error 10 writing to inode 71172122 starting block 26350884)
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1950615457 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1950615457 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 243826688, lost sync page write
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_journal_check_start:83: comm kworker/u16:3: Detected aborted journal
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda1-8.
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1953 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x3800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1953 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x3800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] EXT4-fs (sda1): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] EXT4-fs (sda1): I/O error while writing superblock
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] EXT4-fs (sda1): I/O error while writing superblock
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] EXT4-fs (sda1): Remounting filesystem read-only
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] EXT4-fs (sda1): Remounting filesystem read-only
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] EXT4-fs (sda1): failed to convert unwritten extents to written extents -- potential data loss!  (inode 71172122, error -30)
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_writepages: jbd2_start: 17407 pages, ino 71172122; err -30
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 26349615
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 26349616
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 26349617
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 26349618
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 26349619
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 26349620
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 26349621
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 26349622
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 26349623
[mer. mai 29 12:23:10 2024] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 26349624
[mer. mai 29 12:23:11 2024] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[mer. mai 29 12:23:11 2024] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[mer. mai 29 12:23:11 2024] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:0c:dc:41:a9:c6:5d:a9:86:dd SRC=2a02:2f05:f20b:3200:d48a:fe68:9321:33a5 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:000c LEN=655 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=11897 PROTO=UDP SPT=56605 DPT=3702 LEN=615 
[mer. mai 29 12:23:11 2024] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:0c:dc:41:a9:c6:5d:a9:86:dd SRC=2a02:2f05:f20b:3200:eff1:0fa3:3165:2504 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:000c LEN=655 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=670573 PROTO=UDP SPT=41146 DPT=3702 LEN=615 
[mer. mai 29 12:23:11 2024] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:0c:dc:41:a9:c6:5d:a9:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:0451:aee8:76b2:2dc7 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:000c LEN=655 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=533856 PROTO=UDP SPT=50085 DPT=3702 LEN=615 
[mer. mai 29 12:23:11 2024] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[mer. mai 29 12:23:11 2024] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=4001, bcdDevice= 1.00
[mer. mai 29 12:23:11 2024] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[mer. mai 29 12:23:11 2024] usb 2-4: Product: PSSD T7
[mer. mai 29 12:23:11 2024] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Samsung
[mer. mai 29 12:23:11 2024] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: S6WZNS0W713472X
[mer. mai 29 12:23:11 2024] usb 2-4: UAS is ignored for this device, using usb-storage instead
[mer. mai 29 12:23:11 2024] usb-storage 2-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[mer. mai 29 12:23:11 2024] usb-storage 2-4:1.0: Quirks match for vid 04e8 pid 4001: 800000
[mer. mai 29 12:23:11 2024] scsi host2: usb-storage 2-4:1.0
[mer. mai 29 12:23:12 2024] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Samsung  PSSD T7          0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[mer. mai 29 12:23:12 2024] scsi 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[mer. mai 29 12:23:12 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[mer. mai 29 12:23:12 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[mer. mai 29 12:23:12 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[mer. mai 29 12:23:12 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[mer. mai 29 12:23:12 2024]  sdb: sdb1
[mer. mai 29 12:23:12 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[mer. mai 29 12:23:12 2024] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:0c:dc:41:a9:c6:5d:a9:86:dd SRC=2a02:2f05:f20b:3200:d48a:fe68:9321:33a5 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:000c LEN=655 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=1019870 PROTO=UDP SPT=52981 DPT=3702 LEN=615 
[mer. mai 29 12:23:12 2024] EXT4-fs (sdb1): recovery complete
[mer. mai 29 12:23:12 2024] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.

I buy an other cable USB-C and it didn't solve the pb.
Here what lspci give it to me :
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 05)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b5 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b6 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake LPC Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix BC511
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Alcor Micro AU6625 PCI-E Flash card reader controller

